# Is it possible to implement trigger that run on update in other schema

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have two database users on the same server like `test_user`, `test_customer`.

My requirement is to create a trigger in `test_user` that will execute on insertion in any table in both the user `test_user`, `test_customer` like cust_id in Test_customer as well as user_id in Test_user.

How I can I do that?

Comment: I have already mentioned two user means two schema in oracle

Comment: You can't have a trigger that fires for "any table". A trigger is always attached to exactly one table.

Comment: any table means two tables in two different db schema

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is worked for me:

```
create trigger after_update_user

after update on db_test_user.user for each row
  update table db_test_customer.user set field = NEW.field where id = new.id;
```